# Social database storage in Azure for a cordova / ionic app

Tags: angularjs, cordova, azure, ionic-framework

I'm new to cordova and AngularJS. I'm trying to make a social-type app where you can share photos, videos, etc... I choosed Windows Azure as a backend provider for datas, but i'm pretty much lost in all services :

My shares (text, blob, links...) are stored in the table storage of my Azure mobile service. I use the great [Angular Azure Mobile Service plugin](https://github.com/TerryMooreII/angular-azure-mobile-service) to connect my app to the Serice. It works like a charm and i can see my fake posts. I managed to put a facebook auth system and it's working too.

But I'm now working on the social part : I want users to be able to send their posts to only a few members, and be able to select them, make a contact book from their phone contacts, etc...

My question is : Am I seeing this all the wrong way with the table storage and authentication from Azure ? or should I make a real SQL distant table with my own authentication system ? Is the Azure service enough to manage that ?
How do i manage user infos, like username, contacts ? in tables too ?

Thanks for taking the time to answer, i can't find anybody to do it...

Comment: Database choice is a wide-open discussion, from storage type (key/value, column, graph, relational, document) to actual brand of database server, and combination of types/brands. No right or wrong answer, and too broad a question for StackOverflow (since it'll just get you opinions).

Comment: Actually, since I'm using Azure for my backend, i don't think I've got a lot of choices, if I'm not misunderstanding : 

- either I use a real SQL database and in that case, I assume I'll have to use the API service of Azure ?

- either I can stick with the tables storage function to record my user credentials ? 

but i'm not sure about both... I'm just asking for a good direction

Comment: Nope - not true. You have dozens (hundreds?) of choices. Run any database engine you want, within a VM (Linux or Windows). Run in any of Azure's native database services (Table storage, Redis, DocumentDB, SQL Database). Use a 3rd-party database hoster. Spin up 3rd-party database clusters automatically from the portal (e.g. Cassandra). Run whatever you want.

Comment: Ok David, you're just confusing me more :p What is, in your opinion, the easiest way to build this kind of interface (for social sharing) ?

Comment: What I've been trying to say is... There is no best way. I'm simply letting you know that you need to expand your view of the world (at least of Azure). There are LOTS of choices. And you have lots of fun research ahead of you. Nobody here can tell you the best interface for social sharing.

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll search again... It's been 2 days i'm wondering how to do this, considering the litlle i know... I imagine I can write a php or java backend to manage a sql distant base, but i have no idea how to do it exactly, and how to integrate it in azure. Anyway, thanks...